# Combining If-Then statement and loop in VBA

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, vba

If Column F is = "CRDI"

And If any data in column R is "0"

Then Columns S and T need to also be "0"

... but sometimes these columns have non-zero values that come in.. Just need to come up with the macro to get rid of the nonzero values if the other 2 conditions are met.

Please Help....

Am I on the right track at all????

```
Worksheets("EDW_Caxton_Rat_Extract_File_201").Select
Range("A1048576").Select
Selection.End(xlUp).Select

LastRow = ActiveCell.Row - 1

For x = 0 To LastRow

    If Range("F2").Offset(x, 0).Value = "CRDI" And Range("R2").Offset(x, 0) = 0 _
        And Range("T2").Offset(x, 0) <> 0 Then
            Range("T2").Offset(x, 0) = 0
            x = x - 1
    Next x
End If
```

Comment: "but sometimes these columns have non-zero values" Do you mean just S and T sometime have non-zeros,, or S, T and R?  What do you mean by "get rid of nonzeros"? "Get rid of" them in what way, and where are you trying to get rid of them from?

Comment: Column R, S and T all have Zeros and Non-zero values... after filtering for "contains" CRDI in column F...I want to select all the zeros in column R... Then => Both column S and Column T need to be zero when column R is zero... By "get rid of them" I mean make non-zeros become zeros

Comment: `Cells("S2") = "0"` - no offset? `x = x - 1` != `next i`

Answer (score 1):

This does what you described in your comment:

- Filter Column 6 (F) on "CRDI"
- Filter Column 18 (R) on "0"
- Set (visible) values in  Columns S and T to "0" (not including the header row)

---

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub setZeroes()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    With ActiveSheet.UsedRange
        .AutoFilter
        .AutoFilter Field:=6, Criteria1:="CRDI"
        .AutoFilter Field:=18, Criteria1:="0"

        .Range("S" & .Row + 1 & ":T" & .Rows.Count).Value2 = 0
        .AutoFilter
    End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

---

[image: BeforeAndAfter]

Comment: This actually seems to be making all data in column S & T equal to zero even if there is data in column R... is there a way to make it only applicable to the "VisibleRange" when the filter is applied??

Comment: I tested it again and added an image to show test data and result